# JSF Form Based Authentication + Managed Bean login not working

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, authentication, jsf-2, managed-bean

I want to implement a Managed Bean Form Base Authentication, following the [Java EE 6 Turorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxce.html#glxef)
 I got to configure and build all the required elements, such as the login form, the error page, the web.xml security configuration and the Tomcat security realm (JDBC).

**What is the Problem?** The commandButton that is supposed to invoke the login() method in the Managed Bean is not working, I can see the constructor and the getters getting called but the login method and the setters are not.

**What is curious?** If I remove all the security related elements from the web.xml, restart the application and go directly to the login.xhtml form the login() method gets indeed called.

**Conclusion?** There must be something in the JSF implementation that is preventing this Form Based Authentication from working properly if a managed bean is used.

**Note:** The regular j_security_check Form Based Authentication (without using JSF) is working fine.

**Any Ideas?**

### login.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<f:view>
    <h:head>
        <title>Login Form</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h2>Hello, please log in:</h2>
        <h:form id="loginForm">
            <h:messages style="color:red;margin:8px;" />
            Username: <h:inputText value="#{loginBean.username}" />
            <br />
            Password: <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" />
            <br />
            <h:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.login}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

### LoginBean.java

```
package src;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2951813936936766650L;

    public LoginBean() {
        System.out.println("LoginBean()");
    }

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        System.out.println("getUsername() returning: " + this.username);
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        System.out.println("setUserName(" + username + ")");
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        System.out.println("getPassword() returning: " + this.password);
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        System.out.println("setPassword(" + password + ")");
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String dummy() {
        System.out.println("dummy()");
        return "dummy";
    }

    public String login() {
        System.out.println("login()");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try {
            request.login(this.username, this.password);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Login failed."));
            return "error";
        }
        return "index";
    }

    public void logout() {
        System.out.println("logout()");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try {
            request.logout();
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Logout failed."));
        }
    }

}
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>FormBasedManagedBeanAuth</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Tomcat7FormBasedJAAS</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>secured</web-resource-name>
            <description />
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description />
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/faces/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description />
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

### server.xml (tomcat, fragment)

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
    connectionName="database"
    connectionPassword="password"
    connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database"
    driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    roleNameCol="roleName"
    userCredCol="password"
    userNameCol="userName"
    userRoleTable="user_role"
    userTable="user"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not an expert in this area by any means and came across this as I had the same problem. What I ended up doing was having a secure area and a nonsecure area in the web.xml like this...

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SecureArea</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
```

So then I had the following URL for login
/WAR/login.xhtml
and for all the rest of my app
/WAR/secure/*

That way the loginBean could be executed.
Worked like a charm. Im not sure if there is a better way but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your login.xhtml is the secure area, hence no bean may be accessed by an unauthorized user.

You can proceed as you did in your own answer, or you can define a "public" area,
letting everything else secure:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Public Area</web-resource-name>
        <description>Public Area</description>
        <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

now you move login.xhtml to public/login.xhtml and correct the login-config in web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ALMGCCAdminDB</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/public/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/public/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```